# Why isn't the letter-spacing property being applied?

Tags: html, css

```
<span style="font-size:20px;" "font-color: rgb (52, 52, 52,);" "letter-spacing:-50px;">
Syst&eacute;my pre k&uacute;renie
<span style="color: rgb(0, 162, 228);">│</span>
Vodoin&scaron;tal&aacute;cia a kanaliz&aacute;cia
<span style="color: rgb(0, 162, 228);">│</span>
Plynoin&scaron;tal&aacute;cia
<span style="color: rgb(0, 162, 228);">│</span>
Mont&aacute;ž centr&aacute;lnych vys&aacute;vačov
</span>
```

The "letter-spacing:-50px;" DOESN'T work... WHY???

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/text.html#spacing-props

> This value indicates inter-character space in addition to the default
>   space between characters. Values may be negative, but there may be
>   implementation-specific limits. User agents may not further increase
>   or decrease the inter-character space in order to justify text.

The value of -50px is huge and I believe that you are running into a limitation of the implementation.

Comment: Well it's just a testing one... I've tried a lot of values, but no one has worked :/

Comment: Also the style declarations aren't contained in the attribute value for style on the span. Should be  style="font-size:20px; font-color: rgb (52, 52, 52); letter-spacing:-50px;"

Comment: When you want to declare more than one CSS property inside the style attribute in HTML, they should all be contained inside one set of quotes and separated with semi-colons, eg style="attribute:1; attribute:2; attribute:3;"

Comment: @AndyBursh - I think I learned to read the questions a bit closer.